# Python Pandas DataFrame Fill Missing Value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I have a dataframe like this with some NaNs:

df:

```
      0      1
1  11.0  111.0
2  12.0  112.0
3  13.0  113.0
4   NaN  114.0
4  15.0    NaN
5  16.0  116.0
6  17.0  117.0
7  18.0  118.0
```

So what should I do to it to get the following:

```
      0      1
1  11.0  111.0
2  12.0  112.0
3  13.0  113.0
4  15.0  114.0
4  15.0  114.0
5  16.0  116.0
6  17.0  117.0
7  18.0  118.0
```

So that the NaN values in the index 4 are filled with index 4 values from other rows which are not NaN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can group by index and `ffill()` + `bfill()` inside each group:

```
In [165]: df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
Out[165]:
      0      1
1  11.0  111.0
2  12.0  112.0
3  13.0  113.0
4  15.0  114.0
4  15.0  114.0
5  16.0  116.0
6  17.0  117.0
7  18.0  118.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you have other solutions cuz the things is that I want to have the rows which have the same index to fill each other? ffill() and bfill() may affect other data in that column if there are other nans.

Comment: @Kid that is why , MaxU combine them within the groupby